# String to get string to second line?

Tags: php, css, string, split

I have a post form in my website.

How do I get the string go automatically go to the second line if it's written without spaces?

Example:

```
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
```

I want:

```
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
```

Comment: What language are you using and do you want to do this client or server side?

Comment: Search is your friend... [`string wordwrap ( string $str [, int $width = 75 [, string $break = "\n" [, bool $cut = false ]]] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) and [How to use wordwrap or otherwise to break text to fit a fluid-width div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467545/how-to-use-wordwrap-or-otherwise-to-break-text-to-fit-a-fluid-width-div)

Comment: `<?php $str = 'kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk';
echo chunk_split($str, 30);?>`

Comment: @tunaki        Im using php

Comment: @tunaki found it ;) ty

Comment: @Tony PLEASE MARK AND UP-VOTE THE ANSWER FOR OTHERS HELP. THANKS.

Comment: I am deleting my answer because even after getting correct answer @Tony is not interested in marking the answer as correct.

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry for that. I'm new user @Anant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `wordwrap` function:

```
<?
$text = "kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");
?>
```

Comment: your code have some error, may be TYPO, please check once.